Connecting another server to traefik under an another domain
I have Traefik configured for a specific domain zone along with subdomains. I need to redirect a request coming from a different domain name to another IP address (another physical machine). I can't figure out how to implement this in Traefik.
traefik:
    image: "traefik:latest"
    container_name: "traefik"
    restart: "always"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.network=main_net"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=my@email.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/volumes/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-compress.compress=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.domain1.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"

All subdomains located on the CURRENT machine are working in the current configuration. But I need to make the request from *.domain2.tech redirect to another physical machine that is on the shared network.

I recommend you to take a look at traefiks documentation. Especially considering routers and services.
There are multiple useful router rules that act like a matcher to match your requests. One of those matchers is called "HostRegexp". As the name implies, it will parse given regular expressions.
In order to use any subdomain of "domain2.tech", you might want to use "{subdomain:[a-z0-9-]+}.domain2.tech"
In order to pass the traffic to a given host you can use the loadbalancer's "url" parameter of your service.
Both together you might want something as the following:
- traefik.http.routers.domain2.entrypoints=websecure
- traefik.http.routers.domain2.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9-]+}.domain2.tech`)
- traefik.http.routers.domain2.service=domain2-service
- traefik.http.services.domain2-service.loadbalancer.server.url="http://192.168.0.1" (or any ip)

As a little tip, i would use a .yaml file in order to make static traefik routes instead of using labels. It is way more readable and can be better organized. For more see "Example with a File Provider".

The fact is that the second server (the second Traefik) cannot receive certificates from Lets'encrypt.

I don't really understand what you're saying here. So was the root issue a certificate issue or is this a contributing factor for you?
